# AWS CLI "$ aws configure" creates .awsconfig and .awscredentials files instead of .aws/config and .aws/credenatials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

While configuring my access keys in AWS CLI, there is an issue with credentials and config file creation. when using `"$ aws configure --profile xxxxx"` command.
It used to work fine, `"$ aws configure --profile xxxxx"` would create .aws/config and .aws/credentials files, through which I was able to run any aws commands, while in any of the drives or folder through cli.
I uninstalled and reinstalled AWS CLI for the latest version.
Now `"$ aws configure --profile xxxxx"` just created .awsconfig and .awscredentials files in the same old path (C:\Users\Profile).

- I can run any aws command and get the required output.
- But, when I change my path, like moving to another folder, it throughs an error `"The config profile (xxxxx) could not be found".`

There are no documents in AWS regarding this issue.

Comment: Do you have `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` set somewhere? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

Comment: @DanielScott yes, thanks. I was able to find the issue. I wanted to set the env variables so used the $setx commands
$setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 

$setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 

$setx AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 

$setx AWS_PROFILE 

$setx $AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE

$setx $AWS_CONFIG_FILE

So whenever I tried to $aws configure, instead of .aws folder, .awsconfig and .awscredentials files were created which were not global.

By using $unset , I was able to remove all these and $aws configure now creates folder .aws with config and credentials files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue. I wanted to set the env variables so used the
$setx commands

```
$setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
$setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
$setx AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
$setx AWS_PROFILE 
$setx AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE 
$setx AWS_CONFIG_FILE
```

So whenever I tried to `$aws configure`, instead of the `.aws` folder, .awsconfig and .awscredentials files were created which were not global. By using `$unset`, I was able to remove all these and `$aws configure` now creates `folder .aws with config and credentials files.`

Hopes this helps.
@DanielScott